# Structure de "que la mission de poursuivre l’aventure, d’emmener L’Express explorer"

Tags: grammaire

De l’Express:

> C’est assurément une fierté d’être en capacité de se prévaloir d’un tel héritage. Et une lourde et belle responsabilité pour les équipes de 2018 **que** la mission de poursuivre l’aventure, d’emmener L’Express **explorer** longtemps encore les champs de l’actualité pour en extraire le plus signifiant et en rendre compte à ses lecteurs.

La structure grammaticale de la deuxième phrase me confond. Après "que" j'attends une phrase complète, mais je n'en vois pas. Et que veut dire "d'emmener l'Express explorer" ici ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Encore une autre fonction de *que*

Ceci est une construction répandue en français, ici un peu déguisée. À l'essentiel il ne faut que :

> C'est [prédicat] que [sujet]
>
> *C'est un monstre que ce lion !*

Cette expression est l'équivalente de :

> [sujet] est [prédicat]
>
> *Ce lion est un monstre !*

Or l'expression est déguisée ici par l'ellipse de « c'est », ce qui est un choix un peu plus stylistique.

> Une belle responsabilité que de s'occuper d'un vieux jardin.
>
> *S'occuper d'un vieux jardin est une belle responsabilité.*

Depuis ce dernier exemple tu trouveras facile de comprendre le tien.

---

2. emmener explorer

Les verbes de mouvement peuvent souvent se suivre d'un verbe à l'infinitif qui représente ce qu'on veut faire à la destination. Tu reconnaîtrais probablement des énoncés comme le suivant :

> Je crois aller acheter du lait.

Bien, on peut substituer pour « aller » d'autres verbes de mouvement, y compris :

> Elle court ramasser le ballon.
>
> Nous sortons chanter des chants de Noël chez les voisins.

Et finalement un verbe transitif peut aussi remplir cette fonction :

> Je te prends danser ce soir, mon vieux.

D'où la phrase que tu as citée :

> emmener l'Express explorer
>
> *emmener l'Express quelque part pour qu'il explore*

Answer (score 2):

La phrase devient plus compréhensible si l'on ajoute les parties sous entendues reprises des phrases précédentes.

> **C'est** une lourde et belle responsabilité que la mission de poursuivre l'aventure.

ce qui veut dire :

> La mission de poursuivre... est une lourde et belle responsabilité.

De même :

> **C'est une lourde et belle responsabilité** d'emmener l'Express explorer...

signifie :

> Emmener l'Express explorer les champs de l'actualité est une lourde et belle responsabilité.

La structure de la première phrase se retrouve par exemple dans :

> C'est une chose sérieuse que de se battre (Alexandre Dumas, *Gabriel Lambert, le Bagnard de l'Opéra*, 1844)